# Does $h \circ f = I = f \circ g \implies h = g$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose that the identity function $I$ is defined as $I:X \to X$ such that $\forall x \in X$, $I(x) = x$.
I was hoping that $f(g(x)) = h(f(x)) = x \implies g(x) = h(x)$ for a proof I am constructing. I am stuck as to where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: $f \circ g = \operatorname{id}_X$ shows that $f$ is surjective, and $h \circ f = \operatorname{id}_X$ shows that $f$ is injective. Altogether we have that $f$ is bijective. Then by composing with $f^{-1}$, we have $g = f^{-1} = h$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
h = h\circ\operatorname{id}_X = h\circ (f\circ g) = (h\circ f)\circ g = \operatorname{id}_X\circ g = g
$$

Comment: Absolutely right and succinct. Thanks for your answer, this helps a lot!

Answer (score -1):

If $h(f(x))=x$ then it is also true that $f(h(x))=x$ now if $f$ is inyective we are done. If not there is no such inverse of $f$ for all the reals because then if $a$ and $b$ has the same image in $f$, $h$ will have to give different values for those images, which by definition is not a function.

Comment: $h(f(x)) = x$ does not imply that $f(h(x)) = x$. Consider for example $f(x) = e^x$, $h(x) = \log(x)$ if $x> 0$, $h(x) = 0$ if $x\leq 0$.

Comment: well but it's true $e^{ln(x)}=ln(e^x)=x$

Comment: Only if $x >0$. $f (h (0))=e^{0}=1\neq0$ in my example.

Comment: Well the limit of $h(x)$ when $x\rightarrow 0$ is $-\infty$ and the limit of $f(x)$ when $x\rightarrow -\infty$ is $0$.

Comment: Limits are completely irrelevant here.